# virtual function in C++ must be implemented?

Tags: c++, virtual

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    virtual void func();
};
class B:public A
{
    void func(){}
}
```

if the `func` isn't implemented, there will be linkage error when I define one object of `A`. So why? I haven't call `func`.

Comment: FWIW I get a compiler error, not a linker error. My error is `"undefined reference to 'vtable for A'"`

Comment: What did you expect? What would it mean to do this: `A a; a.func();`? You're calling a method that isn't implemented.

Comment: @RaymondChen the code doesn't do that though. And with non-virtual functions it is correct to omit the definition of a function that's never called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if the func isn't implemented, there will be linkage error when I define one object of A. So why?

Because the standard says that the function must be defined in this case (emphasis mine):

> [class.virtual]
>
> A virtual function declared in a class **shall be defined**, or declared pure ([class.abstract]) in that class, or both; no diagnostic is required ([basic.def.odr]).

As lack of definition for a non-pure virtual function does not conform to the standard, the standard doesn't require that a tool chain would successfully produce an executable.

If the linker was able to diagnose the missing definition, then you can consider yourself lucky, as the diagnostic is not mandated by the standard. If the message was vague, well, there is a reason why the diagnostic isn't mandated. It's not easy for the linker to find out why the source is broken.

Comment: @PasserBy sure. GCC for example doesn't provide any error [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8c23b534fd5453b). If optimisation is disabled, the linker does fail with [*messages*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/064e578246918910), but the messages (`undefined reference to vtable`, `undefined reference to typeinfo`) aren't really able to diagnose the actual cause of the error, but rather complain about something that the programmer is only responsible for indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual function must be implemented， unless it’s a pure virtual function.